# Converting a DataFrame column into list of pairs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
  col_1
A   2   
B   8    
C   4    
D   3
E   1
```

I would like to convert this into something like :

```
[[1,2],[3,4],...]
```

I have tried a for loop

```
def get_pair(col):
    lst = sorted(list(col))
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(col)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(lst)):
            pair = [lst[i], lst[j]]
            pairs.append(pair)
    return pairs
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this in Pandas?

Comment: whats the logic to pair. first and second is a pair, 3rd and 4th is a pair, and so on?

Comment: ``np.reshape(df.col_1.to_numpy(), (-1, 2))`` ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes,right. [1st,2nd],[3rd,4th] and so on

Comment: @sammywemmy, great response. I would just add .tolist().  `np.reshape(df.col_1.to_numpy(), (-1, 2)).tolist()`

Comment: @sammywemmy @JoeFerndz if my column cannot be reshaped to the shape of 2, is there something I can do for that situation? Now I have 6129 elements in the `col1`

Comment: hey @prb, hope the answers below are sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## solution for even or odd # of items; using numpy

Expanding on the wonderful idea that @sammywemmy provided, I am using numpy. The below solution will take care of even or odd numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

#check length of df. If len is odd, get items upto n-1
x = len(df)
y = x if x%2 == 0 else x-1

#reshape only n-1 items if n is odd
z = np.reshape(df.col_1.to_numpy()[:y], (-1, 2)).tolist()

#if n is odd, then append nth item with None.
if x != y: z.append([df.values.tolist()[-1][0],None])

#print result
print (z)
```

The output will be:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, None]]
```

If you want the result set to look like this:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

then change the `z.append` line to

```
if x != y: z.append(df.values.tolist()[-1])
```

## Solution if list is even number of items

Assuming that your DataFrame is an even list of items, you can use `iterrows()` and `list comprehension` to get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
print (df)

a = [[v['col_1'],df.iloc[i+1]['col_1']] for i,v in df.iloc[::2].iterrows()]
print (a)
```

This will give you:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: I think I need to edit my question. What will be the case if the list is not even?
`{'col_1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}`

Comment: @prb, i expanded on sammywemmy's idea and posted a response that should address the odd number in your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `list comprehension`:

```
In [644]: df
Out[644]: 
   col_1
A      1
B      2
C      3
D      4

In [656]: l = df.T.values.tolist()[0]

In [672]: pairs = [l[:c][-2:] for c, i in enumerate(l, 1) if c % 2 == 0]

In [673]: pairs
Out[673]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: @prb: Try my solution.

Comment: I tried. It does not print the last item. It prints `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]` for values 1 thru 9

Answer (score 1):

The other answers should work fine; this is an alternative, using [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) :

```
from itertools import zip_longest

box = df.col_1.array

list(zip_longest(box[::2], box[1::2]))

[(2, 8), (4, 3), (1, None)]
```

Comment: if OP is looking for a nested list instead of tuples inside a list, then we need to do an extra round with `list` then `map` then `list` with `zip`. `list(map(list,zip_longest(box[::2], box[1::2])))`